# plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) not working in my wordpress plugin development

Tags: wordpress, maven-plugin-development

This is my plugin directory access when I use `plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)`

```
http://127.0.0.1/WordPressProject/myplugin/wp-content/plugins/advanced-plugin/admin/
```

But I want to access to `http://127.0.0.1/WordPressProject/myplugin/wp-content/plugins/advanced-plugin/`
After using the function it includes with

> `admin`

folder. not the base plugin base url
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );` for the URL and `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );` for the path.

Pass the plugin’s main file to both functions to get similar results.

```
plugins_url( string $path = '', string $plugin = '' )
```

Retrieves a URL within the plugins or mu-plugins directory.

For [more information](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_url/#more-information)

Comment: Finally I got a solution by using plugin_dir_url(dirname(__FILE__))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks
Finally I got a solution by using

> `plugin_dir_url(dirname(FILE))`